# A for loop in Java?

Tags: java

Here is the problem:

Write a method stutter that takes an ArrayList of Strings as a parameter and that replaces every string with two of that string. For example, if the list stores the values {"how", "are", "you?"} before the method is called, it should store the values {"how", "how", "are", "are", "you?", "you?"} after the method finishes executing.

My code:

```
public void stutter(ArrayList<String> list){

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size() * 2; i+=2){
        list.add(i, list.get(i));
    }
}
```

However, my code gives an IndexOutofBounds error. The correct code should have had the `for` loop be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += 2) {
```

Why is my code is wrong? When I look at the correct answer I feel like it would be wrong because you increment `i` by two every time. So wouldn't that mean by the 3rd time you loop around, `i` would be 4 and that would be greater than list.size() which is 3?

On a side note, while in a `for` loop, when you re-loop around multiple times, does the value of list.size() change? Or will it constantly stay at three through the entire `for` loop process?

Answer (score 5):

The 'trick' in the 'correct' code is that each time you add a member to the list, the size() grows.... and as a result, by the time you have got to the end of the loop you have doubled the size of the list.

The critical component here is that the end-condition of the loop: `i < list.size()` is evaluated ***every*** time the loop iterates, and it is different each time because the inside of the loop adds content.